# AFNetworking: set GET params *and* intercept redirects

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 in an iOS project, and I'm trying to build a GET request with some parameters, *and* intercept redirects.

I see the method `-[AFHTTPRequestOperation setRedirectResponseBlock]`, which I'm using to grab the redirects and do something with them.  But I don't see how to set the request parameters on that operation. Here's what that looks like:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *ballotOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];

    [ballotOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"in completion");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"in error");
    }];

    [ballotOperation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {
        if (redirectResponse == nil) {
            return request;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"in redirect, blocking");
            [ballotOperation cancel];
            return nil;
        }
    }];

    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].operationQueue addOperation:ballotOperation];
```

I see `AFHTTRequestOperationManager` has the method `GET:parameters:success:failure:` in which you can set the parameters.  But that starts the request immediately, not giving me a chance to set the redirect block on it.

I see some sample code out there from AFNetworking 1.x using `AFHTTPClient`, but I don't want to go back!

How can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: could you provide some code?

Comment: Added code I'm using for the redirect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager GET...]` method in `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m` is just a wrapper around creating a `AFHTTPRequestOperation` object and adding it to the operationQueue. Using this as an example, you can accomplish what you are trying to do.

This is how the request is created in the `GET` method of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:manager.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters error:nil];
```

where `urlString` is a NSString representing the url, and parameters are an NSDictionary.

I believe the rest of your code should work, but just in case, here is how it is done in the `GET` method (with your redirect block added as well):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *ballotOperation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"in completion");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"in failure");
}];

[ballotOperation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {
    if (redirectResponse == nil) {
        return request;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"in redirect, blocking");
        [ballotOperation cancel];
        return nil;
    }
}];

[manager.operationQueue addOperation:ballotOperation];
```